# Invalidate is not redrawing the screen. Android

Tags: android, scroll, textview, redraw, invalidation

```
BufferedReader hl  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lines)));
                while(hl.ready()){
                    showLines.append(hl.readLine()+"\n");
                    showLines.invalidate();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
```

That is my code but it is not redrawing when I tell it to.  It is supposed to redraw after every line that is added to textview, but it still only redraws at the end?  Can someone please help me, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is bacause your invalidate() is in a thread while loop and is being acummulated, so to speak, until the loop ends, and only than it draws...

I had the same problem when using Thread.sleep() within a loop. You can use a post delayed method to draw each line, which in this case is one line per second:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    BufferedReader hl  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text))); 
    TextView showLines = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    appendLines(hl, showLines);

}


public void appendLines(final BufferedReader br, final TextView tv){
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
         public void run() {                
             try {
                if(br.ready()){                     
                     try {
                        tv.append(br.readLine()+"\n");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                     
                     tv.invalidate();                     
                     appendLines(br, tv);             
                     }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
         }
         }, 1000); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> That is my code but it is not redrawing when I tell it to.

`invalidate()` does not happen immediately when you call it. `invalidate()`, like `append()` and anything else involving the UI, puts a message on a message queue, that will be processed by the main application thread as soon as you let it. Since you are wasting the user's time in pointless `sleep()` calls, plus doing flash I/O, in a loop on the main application thread, the main application thread cannot process the messages on the message queue. It will process all of your `invalidate()` and `append()` calls after your loop is over and you return control to Android from whatever callback you are in.

> It is supposed to redraw after every line that is added to textview

No, it isn't.

> but it still only redraws at the end?

Correct.

The simple solution is for you to get rid of the `invalidate()` and the `Thread.sleep(10)` and just load the entire file contents into your `TextView` in one call.

The better solution is for you to read the whole file in via an `AsyncTask`, then append the text to the `TextView` in one call in `onPostExecute()`. If needed, use a `ProgressDialog` or something to keep the user entertained while this is going on.