# why UI processes before a heavy process are not executed first

Tags: android, single-threaded

Considering a simple code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInastanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInastanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final ProgressDialog pdUpdate = new ProgressDialog(this);
        final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                btn.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                int i=0;
                while (i<100){
                    i++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("test","i = " + i);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

By click on `btn` two things should happen: changing the text of the button and counting `i` to 100 with delays of 100 msec (it is just an example to simulate a heavy process like reading file, downloading etc). 
I know the correct way of implementing such codes is to use `AsyncTask` but my question is about how this code is compiled. It is a single thread app. So the compiler reads `btn.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());` first and goes to the next lines of code only after this line is executed (please correct me if I am wrong), but it does not happen. Why?
 In `C#` there is a `Refresh()` method which solves this problem (just call it after UI changes and changes are applied). Is there any similar method in java?
 I appreciate any help.

**EDIT 1**
there question is about the order of the following processes: 
Process 1:

```
 btn.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
```

Process 2:

```
                    i++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("test","i = " + i);
                }
```

No matter which one comes first ( I mean either `btn.onClick(){process1;process2;}` or `btn.onClick(){process2;process1;}`), always the second process is executed first. I mean first I see the counting of `i` in Logcat and then see the changing of the button text.

Comment: You're sleeping a total of 9.9 seconds. I don't know why you need to know how the code is compiled unless you're planning on writing a compiling library, like lambdas or injection. I'm not sure what you're actually asking.

Comment: It has nothing to do with compilers but UI thread ... you set text and block UI thread ... so obviously there was no time to redraw ... in C# there is `Application.DoEvents();` but is a poor man choice ...

Comment: I expect to see the UI change and then counting the `i` in `Logcat`. But what happen is that first counting and then UI change.

Comment: *I expect to see the UI change* your expectations are wrong ... *But what happen is that first counting and then UI change.* ... yeah this is what is expected. You blocked UI thread with loop so there in no redraw

Comment: @selvin: So what exactly does this part of code `btn.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());`? just save the changes to a buffer and waiting until UI thread is free to apply them to UI?

Comment: It just set the text to TextView object ...  nothing more...  ui Thread needs to call TextView.draw to make ui change but you did not allow this

Comment: Not sure what u r expecting, try to reword your question. One hint, right after setting the text compare it again in next line to see if it is changing or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to call any equivalent of `refresh()` in this case. However `Button.setText()` do not redraw the view hierarchy automatically. Instead it passes up the view hierarchy the information that the text changed and that it needs to be redrawn. Ultimately this information reaches the root of the view hierarchy which in turn informs the `Choreographer`. The `Choreographer` schedules the drawing for the next frame. This in turn gets stored in your UI thread's message queue.

So when you put your UI thread to sleep, the layout is not redrawn, but is scheduled to be redrawn. As soon as your thread becomes idle, a messages from message queue start being executed. At some point the `Choreographer` is called with the redraw message and orders the view hierarchy to redraw itself.

Also consider that methods like `Handler.post(Runnable)`, `View.post(Runnable)` and their `postDelayed` counterparts can serve as an alternative to `AsyncTask` if do not need to do a heavy computation, but instead schedule some operation (for example a view update) for later. These use the same mechanism as described above - put a `Runnable` into the thread's message queue, which in turn gets picked up and executed when the thread is idle.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got my answer. But is it possible to change the priority or order of messages in the queue or it is a FIFO queue? because as I mentioned, in C# it is possible to add `btn.Refresh()` after settig text. It changes the text before sleeping.

Comment: @Behy I'm pretty sure there's no public API allowing to do that. Check the `Choreographer`'s documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html

Comment: @ Marc Plano-Lesay Maybe there is another mechanism in C# (I am googling), or it is not really single thread (a seprate thread is responsible for updating the UI for instance). But it happens. I mean Refresh() causes to redraw UI before sleep.

Answer (score 0):

nonono,only your method run finish can it work(exp:just sleep 100 msc without while loop).you can find in google how the java method works.（my english is very poor）

Answer (score 0):

As many people pointed out in the comments, since you are doing your `while` loop within the `onClickListener`the UI thread never gets the chance to `invalidate` your button, and thus redraw said button.

I would think if you wanted to get around this you could simply have another listener related to the redraw process finishing. Take a look at the following from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779860/android-listener-after-redrawing-on-invalidate):

```
public class DrawListenerView extends View{
    private Callback callback;
    public DrawListenerView(Callback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //add your method here you want to call
        //Or use a Callback-pattern 
        callback.finish();
    } 
}

public interface Callback(){
    public void finish();
}
```

You could do your looped sleeping once the draw of your button has finished. This would give you the new text drawn, and then sleep after.

I'm not sure what the application for this would be, however you might consider just disabling the button for some time after they press it if you don't want the user to click it again for whatever amount of time.

Answer (score -1):

Android is managing its own drawing cycles. But you're sharing the main thread with it. You can call [`invalidate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) on a view, which is planning a redrawing of the view. But you'll have to free some time on the main thread fro Android to refresh the UI anyway (`setText()` is probably calling `invalidate()` anyway).

Comment: Im just asking, why negative point? is it wrong? if fixed drawing cycles is correct (I gonna google it) it sounds logically

Comment: @Behy Looking at the other answers, I guess we'll never know, as mine looks correct, albeit light.